# Disable Chrome's scroll preserving feature

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll

I have a page containing a list of items:

[image]

Load more button should load some more items via ajax and append it to the items container preserving current scroll position. So after I click it the feed I expect it to look like this (green items are new):

[image]

But in fact Chrome 56 executes some computations to make the page stay in the same state, and what I see looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this smart scrolling position setting in Chrome?

Update: I can reproduce the behavior only if parent container ('body' in my case) has 'display: flex' property (I use it to achieve 'sticky footer' feature).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved a similar problem by adding `overflow-anchor: none;` to the scroll container.

https://wicg.github.io/ScrollAnchoring/

Comment: Awesome, thank you!
I had to set the property not to the scroll container but to another block which was under the container and Chrome used is as base for scroll detection.
Anyway, this specification is exactly the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Today it seems that this property was excluded? When adding 'overflow-anchor: none;' as style on a div element I get the message: Validation (CSS 3.0): "overflow-anchor" is not a known css property name.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Before performing your AJAX call, save the scroll position of the page to a variable, then, after the call, scroll to the position indicated by that variable. Here is what you should write before your AJAX call:

```
var scrollpos = window.scrollY;
```

and here is the code after your AJAX call

```
window.scrollTo(0,scrollpos)
```

Hope this works

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think we also have to listen to 'scroll' event after the loading is initiated, because if during the loading user decided to scroll to the top of the page later jump to the loaded items won't feel like a native experience.

Comment: It also bothers me that other browsers handle the loading in correct way natively. Of course, I can include check for Chrome browser UA and then execute the aforementioned code, but it doesn't feel as a nice and pretty solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why chrome makes calculations to preserve the scroll position? Usually the page will only be longer, so the scroll position stay fixed anyway.
I assume you remove the button, so the position cannot be kept, while content was not reloaded. You should reserve the button space in the dom and remove the reserved space when inserting the reloaded items.